# What should be used for endpoint in renovate-bot config.json?

Tags: npm, renovate, devsecops

I am trying to set up `config.json` for Bitbucket Cloud to automatically update dependencies in npm repos of Bitbucket Cloud. I found one example, but cannot figure out two things:

1. endpoint - what should go there (ABC)? - our company's bitbucket namespace link looks like: https://bitbucket.org/uvxyz/
2. Can I use renovate-bot to issue PRs without bitbucket pipelines? If so, can I make renovate to update only particular repo or repos via config.json mods or I shall put `renovate.json` file in each repo where automatic dependency update is required?

appreciate any examples on the latter.

```
config.json: 
module.exports = {
  "platform": "bitbucket",
  "username": "<my.username>",
  "password": "<bitbucket token on my account>",
  "endpoint": "ABC",
  "hostRules": [
    {
      "hostType": "bitbucket",
      "domainName": "ABC",
      "timeout": 10000,
      "username": "<my.username>",
      "password": "<bitbucket token on my account>"
    }
  ]
};
```

Answer (score 0):

according to the code:

```
const BITBUCKET_PROD_ENDPOINT = 'https://api.bitbucket.org/';
const defaults = { endpoint: BITBUCKET_PROD_ENDPOINT };
```

there's a default, it works for me without setting it
what you see in the [documentation](https://docs.renovatebot.com/modules/platform/bitbucket/) is all you need

Comment: do you put these const(s) into config.js of renovate?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get renovate working with BB after putting the following configuration into its config.js file as

```
{
  hostType: 'bitbucket',
  matchHost: 'https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/',
  username: "bb-username",
  password: "<special app password generated for bb-username>",
}
```

for BitBucket app passwords please look at
https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/create-an-app-password/
and
https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/app-passwords/